# How to solving TypeError: metaData should be of type "object" on upload to minio

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, file-upload, minio

I want to upload a file to minio, but when I run it I get an error like this

```
TypeError: metaData should be of type "object"

at Client.fPutObject (/Users/berliana/Documents/nodejs-simple-file-upload/node_modules/minio/dist/main/minio.js:1210:15)
    at Client.<anonymous> (/Users/berliana/Documents/nodejs-simple-file-upload/node_modules/minio/dist/main/helpers.js:74:51)
    at /Users/berliana/Documents/nodejs-simple-file-upload/server.js:51:17
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/berliana/Documents/nodejs-simple-file-upload/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/berliana/Documents/nodejs-simple-file-upload/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Immediate._onImmediate (/Users/berliana/Documents/nodejs-simple-file-upload/node_modules/multer/lib/make-middleware.js:53:37)
    at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:466:21)
```

this is my code

```
var minioClient = new minio.Client({
endPoint: 'play.min.io',
port: 9000,
useSSL: true,
accessKey: 'myaccesskey',
secretKey: 'mysecretkey'
});

app.post("/uploadfile", multer({dest: "./uploads/"}).single("files"), function(request, response) {
    minioClient.fPutObject("berliana", request.file.originalname, request.file.path, "application/octet-stream", function(error, etag) {
        if(error) {
            return console.log(error);
        }
        response.send(request.file);
    });
});
```

Help me solve this

Answer (score 0):

pass the metadata as an object (as indicated by the error):

```
    minioClient.fPutObject("berliana", request.file.originalname, request.file.path, {"Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"}, function(error, etag) {
        if(error) {
            return console.log(error);
        }
        response.send(request.file);
    });
```